# Regarding Schengen Visa company sponsor to Europe for 6 months, for me. With that Schengen visa can I apply for my dependent

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a Schengen visa sponsored by present company. With that same Schengen visa can I take my dependent wife with me?

Otherwise can I opt for a separate Schengen Visa for my wife?

Comment: There are some employment visa that will allow your dependents to get a visa as well. Questions like that are better asked on Expatriates.SE.

Comment: @o.m. What makes you think it's not about a short-stay visa? In any case, the answer is almost certainly the same. The OP and his wife cannot travel with one visa, he can at best sponsor a visa for her.

Comment: Are you sure you have a Schengen visa? How long will you stay in Europe?

Answer (score 2):

No, your wife needs a visa of her own and she has to apply for it using the regular procedure. She can of course specify that you would be travelling together and add information about your employment, etc. but she will have to provide all the relevant information about herself first.